# Error when getting ContextMenu and adding new item

Tags: contextmenu, javafx-8, menuitem

So I have controller class with this object:

```
 @FXML
    private TextArea textArea;
```

then Im trying to add new MenuItem to its standard Items(that is "copy" and "select all")

```
 @Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        ContextMenu contextMenu = textArea.getContextMenu();
     X  contextMenu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("chuj"));
        textArea.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
```

and line marked with X gets me null pointer exception. Why?
Interesting part is that I can get contextMenu from textArea and set it back to its place with no error. I just cant add something new.

Comment: If you haven't set a context menu, then getContexMenu() will return null.

Comment: there is basic contextmenu already - "copy" and "selectAll". Cant I just add something to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no current way to access the default context menu, which is private API in the `TextInputControl`. This is a [known bug](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-23213).

If you set a context menu, it will remove the default one. You can recreate most of the functionality in the default context menu as these simply map to public methods defined in `TextArea`. The exceptions are "undo" and "redo".

So you can do something like this:

```
private List<MenuItem> createDefaultMenuItems(TextInputControl t) {
    MenuItem cut = new MenuItem("Cut");
    cut.setOnAction(e -> t.cut());
    MenuItem copy = new MenuItem("Copy");
    copy.setOnAction(e -> t.copy());
    MenuItem paste = new MenuItem("Paste");
    paste.setOnAction(e -> t.paste());
    MenuItem delete = new MenuItem("Delete");
    delete.setOnAction(e -> t.deleteText(t.getSelection()));
    MenuItem selectAll = new MenuItem("Select All");
    selectAll.setOnAction(e -> t.selectAll());

    BooleanBinding emptySelection = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() ->
        t.getSelection().getLength() == 0,
        t.selectionProperty());

    cut.disableProperty().bind(emptySelection);
    copy.disableProperty().bind(emptySelection);
    delete.disableProperty().bind(emptySelection);

    return Arrays.asList(cut, copy, paste, delete, new SeparatorMenuItem(), selectAll);
}
```

Now you can do

```
public void initialize() {
    ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
    contextMenu.getItems().addAll(createDefaultMenuItems(textArea));
    contextMenu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("chuj"));
    textArea.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
}
```

It's a bit of a hack (replicating functionality, etc) and you lose the undo/redo (which is a real issue); but it's the best I can suggest until they fix the bug. I suggest you vote for it...